# Can a plural noun be referred to as it?

Tags: reference

What does ***it*** refer to in the passage? Does ***it*** refer to the preceding sentence? Or, can a plural noun be referred to as ***it***? That is, does the author refer to ***daily activities*** as ***it***?

> The researchers analyzed the journals to see what the kids had been
> thinking. By reflecting on how their daily activities supported their
> values, students had gained a new perspective on those activities and
> choices. Little stresses and hassles, like having to fill out job
> applications or give younger siblings a lift, were now demonstrations
> of their values in action–a bold and important step toward their
> future career, a loving gesture of their commitment to family.
> Suddenly, their lives were full of meaningful activities. And all they
> had to do was write about ***it***.

[Connect With the Meaning In Your Life](https://www.kristineklussman.com/connect-with-meaning-in-your-life/)

Comment: ***It*** there refers to the "substance" of the preceding sentence -  *[**the fact that**] their lives were full of meaningful activities*. Or maybe it goes all the way back to ***a new perspective*** if you *insist* on finding something. But it's an "awkward" context, and although I myself would probably use ***it***, I couldn't seriously argue with someone else opting for ***them*** (those ***lives***, OR those ***activities*** - it all gets messy at that level).

Comment: I bet you Bruce Wayne is the Batman. *Think about it.*  You never see them together.

Comment: @TimR: Exactly. But I couldn't seriously argue with someone else opting for *...Think about **them**. You never see them both together.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers IMO your first comment should be fleshed out into an answer—maybe mentioning how often "it" can have a sort of universal, very broad, antecedent that isn't directly stated, e.g. Nike's "Just do it."

Comment: @AndyBonner: ***It's*** a tricky one when ***it*** comes to covering all bases. Nobody would argue with *It's raining*, but not everyone would be happy with *It's boring* (for ***This** is boring*, or ***I'm** bored*). We could do with a "Canonical Post #3: What is the Existential **it** and how can I use it?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers Though what the OP has here is somewhere in between. There *is* an implied antecedent, and it's even more coherent than "It's beginning to look a lot like Christmas," but it's not overtly articulated in the preceding sentence(s): as suggested, "the fact that." (I guess it's not unlike "this" in this regard. "This!" "What?" "You know... [gestures vaguely] *this*!")

Comment: @AndyBonner: I expect pedants and "literalists" could make a case for OP's "it" referring back to ***a new perspective.*** OR we could allow that since each individual student only has one life, ***it*** might refer to each student's life. Same as *All they had to do was raise their right **hand*** (ignoring those who think it has to be ***hands*** there).